# Pass entity in a hidden form field type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have been trying to setup a hidden custom field type and a transformer like in this example: https://gist.github.com/bjo3rnf/4061232

What I am trying to accomplish is to pass an entity trough a hidden element, that entity should map the form´s entity but for some reason when it get to the controller it get empty.

Can some one help me on how can I pass an entity trough a form?

Thank you

Comment: you need to post your code...

Comment: take a look at the [GregwarFormBundle](https://github.com/Gregwar/FormBundle)

Comment: Hi @Matteo, GrerwarForm is for Symfony < 2.6 I cud not install it.

Comment: @gp_sflover, I have a mess on my code right now from all the test I need to clean it up show some peaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with the custom type and transformer is probably better, but if you just want a quick hack, you can set your field up as an entity type in the formbuilder

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('yourField', 'entity', array('class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\YourEntity', 'read_only' => true));
    }
```

and then do something like this in your template:

```
<input type="hidden" id="{{ form.yourField.vars.id }}" 
    name="{{ form.yourField.vars.full_name }}" 
    value="{{ form.yourField.vars.value }}" />
{% do form.yourField.setRendered %}
```

Note that this has to be at the top of your form, before you invoke `form_widget()`

Comment: Thank you @LorenzSchaefer I am new into Symfony, can you give me an example on the entity field type in buildForm.